# Set a Date Object Java

Tags: java, date

**I have a date object myDate(say).
After doing the following:**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 24);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,13);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,52);
```

**I want to set the myDate object to the above values and hence show the below output.**

```
Mon Sep 09 13:45:52 PST 2013
```

**Please let me know how to do it.**

Comment: You need to use [SimpleDateFormat Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class DateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date myDate;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 24);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,13);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,52);
        myDate = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println(myDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants September, not October.

Comment: One thing to notice here, the month counter start with 0, so if OP wants September then we need to pass value of 8 `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);`

Answer (score 1):

The months attribute **starts from January = zero**. Why oh why did Sun do such a counter-intuitive thing, I don't know.

```
import java.util.*;

public class DateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date myDate;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 24);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,13);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,52);
        myDate = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println(myDate);
    }
}
```

One other consideration, the output has a timezone in it - if you want the timezone of the Java installation, no probs. If you want PST *and the Java timezone default is somewhere else*, then use the following constructor:

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timezone);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing info as to setting the time zone when a date object is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
myDate.setTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [**SimpleDateFormat**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").format(cal.getTime())
```